# Given a balance value K and number of nodes, find the maximum height of a K-Balanced binary tree

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, tree

**Definition:**

K-Balanced Binary Tree is a binary tree where all nodes are K-Balanced and a Node is K-Balanced if its left and right sub-trees differ in height by at most K

Now the question:

> Given a balance value K and number of nodes, find the maximum height
>   of a K-Balanced binary tree.

For K = 1 and answer is log2(N) + 1. How could we solve this for an arbitrary K?

I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve constructing any kind of tree.

Comment: Hey close voters! Please expatiate why do you think that the question is too broad?

Comment: Most likely they're abusing "too broad" in lieu of "looks like homework".